# Бот-автоответчик на личные сообщения

Tags: бот

Можно ли написать бота-автоответчика для вк, который будет отвечать друзьям, что хозяин вышел из сети и ответит когда зайдет? Например, я вышел из сети и какой-то человек мне написал, а бот ему пишет(с моей страницы): Здравствуйте, Михаил. Ярослав временно вышел из сети, поэтому не сможет вам ответить. Когда Ярослав зайдет, то он вам обязательно ответит.

Comment: Думаю, можно...

Comment: Можно. Методы по работе с личными сообщениями описаны в документации https://vk.com/dev/messages